# Installing Aptana and Eclipse PDT - what should be main and what as a plugin

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I would like to use an IDE for PHP Development using Zend framework & jQuery. I decided to use Aptana Studio. There is no PHP support in [Studio 2][2], so I have to use Eclipse PDT.

My question is should I install Eclipse PDT first and the use Aptana as plugin? or install Aptana Studio and then install Eclipse PDT as a plugin? What are pros & cons of each method if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Eclipse PDT first & use Aptana Studio as a plugin. You will benefit immensely from this, as there is very good support of auto-information for each & every method & class / object, along with its properties. **One thing you need to take care is that you must need to create a Project for each & every work / project, otherwise it (support for auto-information feature) will not work, because Eclipse will search for the main definitions of classes.**

This good information support is not that much prevalent in Aptana Studio if you install it. So it's best to use it as a plugin with Eclipse PDT.

Also you will be able to upload files & use the File Manager with Eclipse PDT, when you have installed the Aptana Studio as a plugin. Eclipse PDT also has a nice debugging feature, along with other useful features (which I've not yet used).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your bolded statement. Is my understanding correct that you mean that I must clarify it to be new "PHP Project" every time I make a new project instead of a general project?

Comment: @Abdul - if you're working on a project based on PHP language and requires auto-info feature, then you need to make a PHP project explicitly, instead of a general project.

Answer (score 1):

here a step by step tutorial to install Eclipse PHP with aptana plugin or aptana studio with pdt plugin:
[http://aptanaandpdt.blogspot.com](http://aptanaandpdt.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Eclipse
2 - Aptana as plugin

As Aptana2 did not support php .... i thick will be better to use it as plugin

Answer (score 0):

Aptana 3.0, still in beta, has support for PHP too (and Ruby on Rails and Python) http://aptana.org/products/studio3

Answer (score 0):

No more in beta stage. 3.6.1 is available.
http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html